# Create flow chart from text editor

Tags: javascript, html, tree

I am looking to create a simple website, however, the solution appears to be much more difficult to achieve than I would hope.

**What I want:**

I want to be able to write directly into the browser, and have it generate a flow chart, terminated with the ENTER key, like the image below (generated with Visio). Essentially, it is a text box, but it dynamically formats the text into nice looking boxes (Note *The blue circles (Time and Author) are there to illustrate that there will be meta data associated with words and sentences.*)

[image: Text to Flow Chart Diagram]

Are there any open source libraries that can do accomplish this?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Unless you have real code related to this issue the question is far too broad

Comment: @charlietfl I will settle for some high level answer. It is not as if I posted a link to my homework assignment and asked you to finish it for me, I took the time to specify what I need, and what I have tried so far. Furthermore, i didn't ask a subjective question like "what is the weirdest reason a user cited for closing your question?"

Comment: No...you posted a spec and asked for someone to write code based on that spec, not to help you resolve specific code issues. Someone with 5K rep should well know that's not how this site works

Comment: @charlietfl There I edited it as per your complaints. However, now I know the answers I will get will not be at all the ones I am hoping for.

Comment: http://www.graphvizrepl.com/ does just that!

Comment: @Sukima Although it solves half of my problem (not having to reinvent the wheel with graphs/nodes), it does not address my main problem right now where I want to seamlessly type into a browser and have it create nodes for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though i must admit **charlietfl** is correct in his statement, i thought it was a fun challenge so i made a fast demo on how you could make it, and from there you could develop it further.

Working [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRjWQd).

I recommend you to change the view settings on the upper right corner.

The design and everything is not near perfect and i diddent take the time to implement an arrow, by looking at the code you should be able to figure out how to make that yourself.

HTML:

```
<div id="flowContainer" class="flowChart">


</div>
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea"></textarea>
<button onclick="postflow()">Post</button>
```

CSS:

```
.flowChart{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  overflow: auto;
}

.textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  resize: none;
}

.chart{
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ea5e00;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.chart p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function postflow(){

  var flow = document.createElement("div");
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
  var text = document.createTextNode(textarea.value);
  textarea.value = "";
  p.appendChild(text);
  flow.className = "chart";
  flow.appendChild(p);
  document.getElementById("flowContainer").appendChild(flow);

}
```